# Angular js: Multiple directives [ionDatetimePicker, ionItem] asking for new isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, datepicker

I am trying to implement datepicker in my android application using the following [ion datepicker](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker) plugin.

I've added the css and js files in my index.html,but i'm getting the following error from my console.

> ionic.bundle.js:20434 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives
>   [ionDatetimePicker, ionItem] asking for new/isolated scope on:

Here is my code

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ion-datetime-picker ng-model="datetimeValue">
        {{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss"}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Note: this is the code sample from their documentation

Comment: could u show us how you included the reference to ur controller ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use these directives separately:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <div ion-datetime-picker ng-model="datetimeValue">
            {{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss"}}
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```